# Clang on Cygwin with C++11

Tags: c++, cygwin, clang++

I installed Clang on Cygwin and I try to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

That works fine if I do `clang++ file.cpp`. It does not work if I do `clang++ file.cpp -std=c++11`. I get errors from standard headers like this:

```
In file included from file.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/ostream:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/ios:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/exception:150:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/exception_ptr.h:132:13: error:
      unknown type name 'type_info'
      const type_info*
```

Does Cygwin Clang just not work with C++11 turned on, or is there something I can do to get around this?

Comment: This is not a warning, this is an error (sidenote).

Comment: @H2CO3 You are right, I wrote the wrong thing. If it was just warnings it would be less of a problem. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you `#include <typeinfo>` (before including *iostream*)?

Comment: @Prætorian It does not make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the standard library. exception_ptr.h is only included in C++11 mode, which is why you don't see it otherwise. The problem is, exactly as the error says, that std::type_info is not declared. It seems GCC magically forward declares certain names in the std namespace which is why it is unaffected! You can prove it yourself with a simple program:

```
namespace std {  

    class A
    {
    public:
         type_info* B();
    };
}
```

This compiles with GCC 4.5.3 but Clang gives an error no matter what the -std setting.

The problem is fixed in the latest version of GCC so manually updating is probably your best bet. The 4.7.2 release configured with --enable-languages=c,c++ compiles no problem under Cygwin.

Comment: Compiling gcc under Cygwin seems to work, but I have had strange issues with the resulting compiler. Be sure to test it carefully.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible and relatively easy to get the Clang package working on Cygwin with C++11.

The error you are describing, for example, is fixed by adding

```
#ifdef __clang__
    class type_info;
#endif
```

to `exception_ptr.h`. Another error which needs to be fixed is to add a copy constructor to `std::pair`.

This is unfortunate, though, and hopefully the Cyginw gcc packages will be updated to a newer version of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default clang on Windows will use an ms-compatiblity mode and ms-extensions. These and other defaults on Windows may not be appropriate for Cygwin.

Use the `-###` flag to get the actual options passed from the driver to the compiler so you can try tweaking them.