# How can this issue with hls4ml be resolved?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vivado

**Disclaimer : I asked this question before looking into compilation error details. [This question contains the answer to the problem explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938663/clang-on-cygwin-with-c11) In short, variable type definition errors in exception definitions prevent synthesis from happening properly.**

Unless you are willing to find the correct `gcc` compiler to run Vivado Synthesis without errors on, I recommend going to Linux for this task.

---

I am attempting to run the example code [as shown on the documentation page of hls4ml](https://fastmachinelearning.org/hls4ml/setup.html#getting-started), but on running the following:

```py
import hls4ml

#Fetch a keras model from our example repository
#This will download our example model to your working directory and return an example configuration file
config = hls4ml.utils.fetch_example_model('KERAS_3layer.json')

print(config) #You can print it to see some default parameters

#Convert it to a hls project
hls_model = hls4ml.converters.keras_to_hls(config)

#Use Vivado HLS to synthesize the model
#This might take several minutes
hls_model.build()

#Print out the report if you want
hls4ml.report.read_vivado_report('my-hls-test')
```

and the output is

```
Downloading example model files ...
{'OutputDir': 'my-hls-test', 'ProjectName': 'myproject', 'XilinxPart': 'xcku115-flvb2104-2-i', 'ClockPeriod': 5, 'Backend': 'Vivado', 'IOType': 'io_parallel', 'HLSConfig': {'Model': {'Precision': 'ap_fixed<16,6>', 'ReuseFactor': '1'}}, 'KerasJson': 'KERAS_3layer.json', 'KerasH5': 'KERAS_3layer_weights.h5'}
Interpreting Model
Topology:
Layer name: input_1, layer type: InputLayer, current shape: [[None, 16]]
Layer name: fc1_relu, layer type: Dense, current shape: [[None, 16]]
Layer name: fc2_relu, layer type: Dense, current shape: [[None, 64]]
Layer name: fc3_relu, layer type: Dense, current shape: [[None, 32]]
Layer name: output_softmax, layer type: Dense, current shape: [[None, 32]]
Creating HLS model
Synthesis report not found.
Found 1 solution(s) in my-hls-test/myproject_prj.
Reports for solution "solution1":

C SIMULATION RESULT:
INFO: [SIM 2] *************** CSIM start ***************
INFO: [SIM 4] CSIM will launch GCC as the compiler.
make: 'csim.exe' is up to date.
INFO: Unable to open input/predictions file, using default input.
0.0292969 0.756836 0.0546875 0.139648 0.0371094 
INFO: Saved inference results to file: tb_data/csim_results.log
INFO: [SIM 1] CSim done with 0 errors.
INFO: [SIM 3] *************** CSIM finish ***************

Synthesis report not found.
Co-simulation report not found.
```

Note that the last two lines refer to the build process and the returning of a report.

*I am running this on Jupyter Notebook (6.0.3) via the Anaconda Navigator, Python version is 3.6.9 and hls4ml version is 0.5.0*

I cannot understand whether this is an error due to the installation or due to the code and so on.

Any thoughts on what causes this?

---

I think this is specific to hls4ml, but sadly it doesn't exist as a tag in StackOverflow.

### Update

The initial problem I had (which was that my directory had a space `' '` which is an illegal character) had me run `vivado_hls -f build_prj.tcl "csim=1 synth=1 cosim=1 export=1"` which showed me a new host of issues. Namely, I am getting these errors:

```
***** C/RTL SYNTHESIS *****
INFO: [SCHED 204-61] Option 'relax_ii_for_timing' is enabled, will increase II to preserve clock frequency constraints.
INFO: [HLS 200-10] Analyzing design file 'firmware/myproject.cpp' ...
ERROR: [HLS 200-70] Compilation errors found: In file included from firmware/myproject.cpp:1:
In file included from firmware/myproject.cpp:19:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\iostream:39:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\ostream:39:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\ios:39:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\exception:151:
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\exception_ptr.h:132:13: error: unknown type name 'type_info'
      const type_info*
            ^
In file included from firmware/myproject.cpp:1:
In file included from firmware/myproject.cpp:19:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\iostream:39:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\ostream:39:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\ios:39:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\exception:151:
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\nested_exception.h:62:5: error: the parameter for this explicitly-defaulted copy constructor is const, but a member or base requires it to be non-const
    nested_exception(const nested_exception&) = default;
    ^
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\nested_exception.h:64:23: error: the parameter for this explicitly-defaulted copy assignment operator is const, but a member or base requires it to be non-const
    nested_exception& operator=(const nested_exception&) = default;
                      ^
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\nested_exception.h:77:28: error: exception specification in declaration does not match previous declaration
  inline nested_exception::~nested_exception() = default;
                           ^
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\nested_exception.h:66:20: note: previous declaration is here
    inline virtual ~nested_exception();
                   ^
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\nested_exception.h:122:61: error: redefinition of default argument
    __throw_with_nested(_Ex&& __ex, const nested_exception* = 0)
                                                            ^ ~
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/win64/tools/clang/bin\..\lib\clang\3.1/../../../include/c++/4.5.2\nested_exception.h:110:56: note: previous definition is here
    __throw_with_nested(_Ex&&, const nested_exception* = 0)
                                                       ^ ~
In file included from firmware/myproject.cpp:1:
In file included from firmware/myproject.cpp:21:
In file included from firmware/myproject.h:23:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_int.h:367:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_fixed.h:55:
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_fixed_base.h:838:13: warning: shift count is negative [-Wshift-count-negative]
      ret.V <<= (_AP_I - _AP_W);
            ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_fixed_base.h:869:69: note: in instantiation of member function 'ap_fixed_base<50, 40, true, 5, 3, 0>::to_ap_int_base' requested here
  inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int to_int() const { return to_ap_int_base().to_int(); }
                                                                    ^
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_fixed_base.h:1042:71: note: in instantiation of member function 'ap_fixed_base<50, 40, true, 5, 3, 0>::to_int' requested here
  inline __attribute__((always_inline)) operator int() const { return to_int(); }
                                                                      ^
firmware/nnet_utils/nnet_activation.h:389:17: note: in instantiation of member function 'ap_fixed_base<50, 40, true, 5, 3, 0>::operator int' requested here
   data_round = (data_cache[jj]-data_cache[ii])*CONFIG_T::table_size/16;
                ^
firmware/nnet_utils/nnet_activation.h:421:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nnet::softmax_legacy<ap_fixed<16, 6, 5, 3, 0>, ap_fixed<16, 6, 5, 3, 0>, softmax_config9>' requested here
        softmax_legacy<data_T, res_T, CONFIG_T>(data, res);
        ^
firmware/myproject.cpp:90:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nnet::softmax<ap_fixed<16, 6, 5, 3, 0>, ap_fixed<16, 6, 5, 3, 0>, softmax_config9>' requested here
    nnet::softmax<layer8_t, result_t, softmax_config9>(layer8_out, layer9_out);
    ^
In file included from firmware/myproject.cpp:1:
In file included from firmware/myproject.cpp:21:
In file included from firmware/myproject.h:23:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_int.h:367:
In file included from D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_fixed.h:55:
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_fixed_base.h:838:13: warning: shift count is negative [-Wshift-count-negative]
      ret.V <<= (_AP_I - _AP_W);
            ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_fixed_base.h:869:69: note: in instantiation of member function 'ap_fixed_base<51, 41, true, 5, 3, 0>::to_ap_int_base' requested here
  inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int to_int() const { return to_ap_int_base().to_int(); }
                                                                    ^
D:/Tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.2/common/technology/autopilot\ap_fixed_base.h:1042:71: note: in instantiation of member function 'ap_fixed_base<51, 41, true, 5, 3, 0>::to_int' requested here
  inline __attribute__((always_inline)) operator int() const { return to_int(); }
                                                                      ^
firmware/nnet_utils/nnet_activation.h:401:27: note: in instantiation of member function 'ap_fixed_base<51, 41, true, 5, 3, 0>::operator int' requested here
      int exp_res_index = exp_res[ii]*CONFIG_T::table_size/64;
                          ^
firmware/nnet_utils/nnet_activation.h:421:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nnet::softmax_legacy<ap_fixed<16, 6, 5, 3, 0>, ap_fixed<16, 6, 5, 3, 0>, softmax_config9>' requested here
        softmax_legacy<data_T, res_T, CONFIG_T>(data, res);
        ^
firmware/myproject.cpp:90:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nnet::softmax<ap_fixed<16, 6, 5, 3, 0>, ap_fixed<16, 6, 5, 3, 0>, softmax_config9>' requested here
    nnet::softmax<layer8_t, result_t, softmax_config9>(layer8_out, layer9_out);
    ^
2 warnings and 5 errors generated.
Failed during preprocessing.
    while executing
"source build_prj.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel \#0 [list source $arg] "

INFO: [Common 17-206] Exiting vivado_hls at Fri Apr  2 16:14:58 2021...
```

I have encountered this issue on both newer and older versions of Vivado HLS. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Right now, this seems to be an issue on Windows, and there is no solution to it. I was directed to using Linux. I will come back to this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, hls4ml is backend Vivado for linux (as of now). It was not a problem in Ubuntu.
Windows is not supported, there's a file that specifically verifies the OS before synthesis.

if you go to your directory where you built the hls model, there in the `build_lib.sh` file

**I am not sure why it is not working but but they are setting the C++ compiler according to the OS** here

```
#!/bin/bash

CC=g++
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
    CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC -std=c++11 -fno-gnu-unique"
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC -std=c++11"
fi
LDFLAGS=
INCFLAGS="-Ifirmware/ap_types/"
PROJECT=myproject
LIB_STAMP=1F075F4e

${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCFLAGS} -c firmware/${PROJECT}.cpp -o ${PROJECT}.o
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCFLAGS} -c ${PROJECT}_bridge.cpp -o ${PROJECT}_bridge.o
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCFLAGS} -shared ${PROJECT}.o ${PROJECT}_bridge.o -o firmware/${PROJECT}-${LIB_STAMP}.so
rm -f *.o
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30712782)

Comment: @Geg My current sucessful workflow is with an older version of hls4ml (hls4ml-0.2.x), where I did convert the keras NN network with its weights to a Vivado HLS project on Windows, and then I transered the Vivado HLS project to an Ubuntu VM with Vivado and Vivado HLS, and it seems to work for me right now, as I'm not into updating anything at the moment. I posted this question while trying to update my workflow and until I need to do so, I'm sailing with the old stuff while it works.